# Problem with DOM in IE

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, dom

I wonder if IE doesn't support DOM method when creating a table in a containing element-div. Because I could not see the table when the JavaScript rendered. Please see the following:

In the HTML:

```
<div id="pageHeader">
    <div id="filters">
       -----
    </div>
</div>
```

In the JavaScript:

I created a div named "classifications". Then I have two sub divs.

1. `<div id="titleClass">`
2. `<div id="namesClass">`

Also, I have one table in number 2. The problem is that div number 2 and its child-table is not seen on screen.

Any solution, please?

Here is the code: supposing that "classifications" is already defined.

```
function loading(){
    initClassifications();
}
function initClassifications() {
    if (classifications.length > 0) {
        var el = document.createElement("div");
        el.setAttribute("id", "classifications");

        ul1 = document.createElement("ul");
        startIndex1 = 0;
        var pageHeader = document.getElementById("pageHeader");
        var titleElement = document.createElement("span");
        var titleText = document.createTextNode("classifications");
        titleElement.appendChild(titleText);
        var lstElement = document.createElement("div");
        lstElement.setAttribute("id", "titleClass");
        lstElement.appendChild(titleElement);
        el.appendChild(lstElement); //add title to classifications
        var names = document.createElement("div"); // create div for classifications
        names.setAttribute("id", "namesClass");
        var tbl = document.createElement("table");
        var tr = document.createElement("tr");
        var td = document.createElement("td");        

        for (var i = 0 ; i < classifications.length && i< 10 ; i++) {                    
            var li = document.createElement("li");
            ul1.appendChild(li);
            names.appendChild(ul1);
            var link = document.createElement("a");
            link.setAttribute("href", classifications[i][0]);
            var name = document.createTextNode(classifications[i][1]);
            link.appendChild(name);
            li.appendChild(link);
            startIndex1++;
        }

        td.appendChild(ul1);
        tr.appendChild(td);
        if (startIndex1 < classifications.length) {
            var span = document.createElement("span");
            var link = document.createElement("a");
            link.setAttribute("href", "javascript:addClassifications();");
            var text = document.createTextNode("more...");
            link.appendChild(text);
            span.appendChild(link);

            moreClass = document.createElement("div"); //more div for moving
            moreClass.setAttribute("id", "moreClass");
            moreClass.appendChild(span);
            el.appendChild(moreClass);
            var td1 = document.createElement("td");            
            td1.setAttribute("valign", "bottom");            
            td1.appendChild(moreClass);
            tr.appendChild(td1);

        }
        tbl.appendChild(tr);
        el.appendChild(tbl);
        names.appendChild(tbl);
        el.appendChild(names);
        pageHeader.appendChild(el);
        var filter = document.getElementById("filters");
        pageHeader.insertBefore(el, filter); //insert listingnames before filters

    }

}
function addClassifications() {
    var maxIndex = startIndex1 + 10;
    for (var i = startIndex1; i < classifications.length && i<maxIndex; i++)
    {     
            var li = document.createElement("li");
            ul1.appendChild(li);
            var link = document.createElement("a");
            link.setAttribute("href", classifications[i][0]);
            var name = document.createTextNode(classifications[i][1]);
            link.appendChild(name)
            li.appendChild(link);
            startIndex1++;          
    }

   //if (startIndex1 >= classifications.length)
     //   $$("#moreClass").remove();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The fact that you've given these divs ids, and that these ids include the word 'Class', suggests that your CSS might be part of the problem. But since you didn't post the CSS, it's a little hard to know.

**EDIT**: OK, now you've posted the code.  It **is** a bit long. For your sake as well as ours, you should try to find the smallest possible example that reproduces the problem that you're trying to solve.

For example, you suggested that IE doesn't allow you to add a table to the DOM via JavaScript. But here's some JavaScript that I just hacked together that does add a table to the DOM.  (The table has one cell, the content of which is `Foo!`)  So the problem you're trying to solve is probably elsewhere.

```
<script>
  var div = document.createElement('div');
  div.id = 'classifications';

  var child1 = document.createElement('div');
  child1.id="titleClass";
  div.appendChild(child1);

  var child2 = document.createElement('div');
  child2.id="namesClass";
  div.appendChild(child2);
  child2.innerHTML = '<table border="1"><tr><td>Foo!</td></tr></table>';

  document.body.appendChild(div);

</script>
```

One thing I noticed, though, is that you're using `setAttribute` to set the id of the elements. In some browsers, and I think IE is one, this doesn't work.  Try just doing

```
   elem.id = <id>
```

and see if that helps.

Comment: I don't think because of CSS. Please let see the whole code then you can test it with ie since it works well in firefox. Thanks!

Comment: Sorry why I can't post my code. it is a bit longer, I guess. let me try again

Comment: Sinai, you'll want to edit the question rather than post the code in a comment. http://stackoverflow.com/posts/1197905/edit

Comment: @Sinal, if Dan's solution was correct, you should accept it. If you found the answer on your own, you should post it and accept that. Doing so helps others with similar issues know what solved the problem for you. (And it awards points to Dan for solving your problem, if indeed he did)

Comment: Dan's example works because it uses the innerHTML attribute to create the table instead of creating it via actual DOM methods.  This is the problem that IE has, its DOM manipulation routines are buggy and slow.  Using innerHTML doesn't allow you to create an entire object hierarchy problematically.   (Also, I realize this is a late comment, but I'm having this exact problem trying to code something for IE 7 today.)  If I open the example John gave in IE 8's debugger and click the 'edit html' button and then press it again, the page renders properly despite no change to the underlying html.

Comment: hehe, programmatically, not problematically.

Comment: @Andrew Young -- if I remember right, I used innerHTML only because it kept the code example shorter. I just tried developing an example that used createChild/appendChild all the way down, and got it to work in IE7, Firefox 6, and Chrome. However, in IE7, you must include an explicit `TBODY` element inside the `TABLE`, and use that as the parent for the `TR` element(s). Chrome and Firefox seem to work with or without the `TBODY`. Rather than editing my example above, I can point you to another example at MSDN: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms532998(v=vs.85).aspx#TOM_DOM

Comment: @Andrew Young -- also, note that Sinal's code did not include an explicit TBODY.